# Does this integral converge over a positive measure?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\lambda$ be a positive measure on $(0;+\infty)$ satisfies
> $\int_{(0,+\infty)} (1+s)^{-1} d \lambda (s) < +\infty$. Does this
> integral converge?
>
> $$\displaystyle\int_{(0;+\infty)} \dfrac{1}{s} d \lambda(s).$$

$\forall n \ge 0$, consider series open set $A_n = \left(\dfrac{1}{n};n\right)$. Clearly, $A_n$ is descending and
$$\bigcap_n A_n = \emptyset.$$
Then,
$$0 = \lambda \left( \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n.$$
Hence, $\exists n \ge 1$ such that $\lambda(A_n) \le \dfrac{1}{2}$. Let $B_n = (0;+\infty) \setminus A_n$, $B_n$ is a positive measure set and $f$ is bounded on $B_n$, therefore
$$\displaystyle\int_{B_n} \dfrac{1}{s} d \lambda(s) < +\infty.$$

Is this correct? Thank all!

Comment: ... nvm.........

Comment: $A_n$ as ascending and $\lim\lambda (A_n)=\infty$.

Comment: Lebesgue measure restricted to $(0,1)$ is clearly  a counter-example.

Comment: I see, so this integral is divergence.